# When we should use ":=" not "=" in chisel3, same case is "when" and "if"

Tags: chisel

Recently I am leraning chisel3, and I have below questions:
   When we should use " := " not " = "
   Same case is "when" and "if".
   Or could you kindly offer some general rules for these cases ?

Another question is about "Wire", what's rule it should be used or not when we declare one val ?

Thanks a lot!
Bibo

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental difference here is certain operations are *Scala operations* and certain operations are *Chisel operations*. Scala operations are evaluated statically to build hardware generators. Chisel operations are used to describe how hardware components are connected and interact. For your two provided examples:

- Scala operations

  - `this = that` does Scala assignment
  - `if (condition) { body }` is a standard conditional
- Chisel operations

  - `this := that` connects one Chisel type to another Chisel type
  - `when (condition) { body }` is a hardware conditional

To concretize this, consider the following Chisel `Module` that mixes Scala operations and Chisel operations.

```scala
import chisel3._
/* param is a Scala Boolean that will change the internals of Foo */
class Foo(param: Boolean) extends Module {
  /* We do Scala assignment of a Chisel type (a Bundle) to value "io" */
  val io = IO(new Bundle{})

  /* We use a Scala conditional to change whether or not "x" will be 
   * a 1-bit wire or a 2-bit wire */
  val x = if (param) { Wire(UInt(1.W)) }
          else       { Wire(UInt(2.W)) }

  /* Finally, we do a Chisel assignment (hardware connection) of x 
   * to a literal 0 */
  x := 0.U
}
```

Behind the scenes, Chisel "operations" are really methods that are defined for Chisel types that use names that look familiar, like `:=` is Chisel connect and `===` is Chisel hardware equality. These must be different from their underlying Scala operations, e.g., `=` is Scala assign and `==` is Scala equality.

---

A `Wire` is needed if you want to describe actual hardware that you can do hardware operations on. Same for a `Reg`. A bare Chisel type, like `UInt` will only generally be used in describing a `Bundle` or in some io. To do hardware connections/operations with this Chisel type, you will need to wrap it in a `Reg()` or a `Wire()`.