# comparing the value in a register to an int

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I am trying to get the value  of a reg and compare it with a number inside and if statement

```
  val refill_addr    = Reg(UInt(width = paddrBits))
if ( refill_addr >  20000.U) 
   cacheable := true
   else 
       cacheable := false
```

but i get this error

```
[error] /home/a/i-rocket-chip/src/main/scala/rocket/ICache.scala:365:18: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.core.Bool
[error]  required: Boolean
[error] if ( refill_addr >  20000.U) 
[error]                  ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `when`/`.otherwise` here instead of `if`/`else`.

`when` is a Chisel (hardware) construct that will eventually map to one or more multiplexers. `if` is a Scala construct and can be used for compile-time generation of hardware.

```scala
when (refill_addr >  20000.U) {
  cacheable := true
} .otherwise {
  cacheable := false
}
```

For some more info, [there was a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644857/when-we-should-use-not-in-chisel3-same-case-is-when-and-if).

Comment: when i do I get this error instead 
```Exception in thread "main" firrtl.passes.PassExceptions: 
firrtl.passes.CheckChirrtl$InvalidLOCException:  @[ICache.scala 367:14:freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.fir@212151.6]: [module ICache] Invalid connect to an expression that is not a reference or a WritePort.
firrtl.passes.CheckChirrtl$InvalidLOCException:  @[ICache.scala 370:18:freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.fir@212154.6]: [module ICache] Invalid connect to an expression that is not a reference or a WritePort.
firrtl.passes.PassException: 2 errors detected!
 
 
```

Comment: This is indicating that you are trying to connect to something (something on the left hand side of a statement) that you cannot connect to. It sounds like this is user error due to the modification you made. Likely, this is due to how you declared `cacheable`. This should be a register, a wire, or a port of a memory, but the FIRRTL compiler is indicating that it isn't. You can start debugging by looking at line 370 of `ICache.scala` or at line 212154 of the generated FIRRTL.

Answer (score 0):

Another convenient and FIRRTL optimized solution is to use `Mux`:

```
val cacheable = Mux(refill_addr > 20000.U, true.B, false.B)
```

For more complex expressions and use cases you can check out [this guide](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Muxes-and-Input-Selection).